# Incorrect dataset obtained from finegray() function (Survival package)

Tags: dataframe, survival-analysis

I investigate the effect of in-ICU transfusion on survival in patients supported by ECMO (a device supplying heart function in human). For these patients there are three outcomes: Death recovery, transplantation or long term mechanical assistance. Thus, death outcome competes with transplantation and long term mechanical assistance.  For this reason I want to perform a Fine and Gray model.

Please find below a reproducible df

```
df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 
61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 
77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 
93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 
107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 
120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 
133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 
146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 
159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 
172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 
185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190), etime = c(366, 26, 366, 34, 17, 
3, 26, 4, 3, 366, 366, 8, 366, 9, 1, 11, 366, 9, 366, 366, 22, 
26, 366, 14, 366, 366, 6, 87, 366, 366, 366, 366, 46, 15, 10, 
19, 366, 6, 24, 24, 14, 366, 14, 25, 6, 366, 366, 366, 366, 10, 
366, 366, 366, 366, 366, 366, 23, 7, 12, 164, 5, 31, 13, 366, 
22, 366, 366, 21, 11, 366, 366, 366, 366, 15, 248, 35, 9, 65, 
7, 366, 4, 22, 20, 320, 6, 5, 7, 32, 6, 3, 10, 15, 4, 5, 366, 
10, 14, 366, 15, 366, 366, 14, 5, 8, 15, 12, 44, 10, 8, 366, 
4, 26, 19, 366, 42, 366, 4, 3, 366, 366, 21, 66, 366, 14, 15, 
13, 366, 5, 12, 366, 366, 3, 366, 366, 7, 6, 366, 366, 9, 7, 
17, 52, 24, 14, 366, 64, 9, 9, 366, 366, 366, 5, 366, 366, 5, 
293, 21, 366, 366, 9, 6, 5, 366, 6, 29, 16, 28, 13, 366, 13, 
16, 15, 9, 10, 16, 11, 6, 11, 9, 366, 366, 366, 15, 14, 42, 54, 
32, 14, 8, 366), event = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L), levels = c("death", "LVAD", 
"recovery", "transplantation"), class = "factor"), bridge = c("3", 
"1", "3", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "3", "3", "0", "3", "0", 
"0", "0", "3", "0", "3", "3", "0", "0", "3", "0", "3", "3", "0", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "0", "0", "3", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "3", "0", "3", 
"3", "0", "0", "3", "3", "3", "3", "0", "3", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"3", "0", "0", "1", "3", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "3", "2", "0", "3", "0", "3", "3", "1", "0", "0", "2", 
"0", "2", "0", "0", "3", "1", "2", "2", "3", "0", "3", "0", "2", 
"3", "3", "0", "0", "3", "0", "0", "2", "3", "0", "2", "3", "3", 
"0", "3", "3", "0", "2", "3", "3", "0", "0", "2", "0", "0", "2", 
"3", "0", "0", "2", "3", "3", "3", "0", "3", "3", "0", "0", "0", 
"3", "3", "2", "0", "2", "3", "0", "0", "3", "0", "2", "3", "2", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "3", "0", "0", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "1", 
"2", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "3"), follow_up_to_bridge = c(366, 
26, 366, 34, 17, 3, 26, 4, 3, 366, 366, 8, 366, 9, 1, 11, 366, 
9, 366, 366, 22, 26, 366, 14, 366, 366, 6, 87, 366, 366, 366, 
366, 46, 15, 10, 19, 366, 6, 24, 24, 14, 366, 14, 25, 6, 366, 
366, 366, 366, 10, 366, 366, 366, 366, 366, 366, 23, 7, 12, 164, 
5, 31, 13, 366, 22, 366, 366, 21, 11, 366, 366, 366, 366, 15, 
248, 35, 9, 65, 7, 366, 4, 22, 20, 320, 6, 5, 7, 32, 6, 3, 10, 
15, 4, 5, 366, 10, 14, 366, 15, 366, 366, 14, 5, 8, 15, 12, 44, 
10, 8, 366, 4, 26, 19, 366, 42, 366, 4, 3, 366, 366, 21, 66, 
366, 14, 15, 13, 366, 5, 12, 366, 366, 3, 366, 366, 7, 6, 366, 
366, 9, 7, 17, 52, 24, 14, 366, 64, 9, 9, 366, 366, 366, 5, 366, 
366, 5, 293, 21, 366, 366, 9, 6, 5, 366, 6, 29, 16, 28, 13, 366, 
13, 16, 15, 9, 10, 16, 11, 6, 11, 9, 366, 366, 366, 15, 14, 42, 
54, 32, 14, 8, 366), one_year_status = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), one_year_fu = c(366, 
155, 366, 366, 17, 3, 26, 4, 3, 366, 366, 8, 366, 9, 1, 11, 366, 
9, 366, 366, 22, 26, 366, 14, 366, 366, 6, 87, 366, 366, 366, 
366, 46, 366, 10, 19, 366, 6, 24, 24, 14, 366, 14, 25, 366, 366, 
366, 366, 366, 17, 366, 366, 366, 366, 366, 366, 23, 7, 366, 
164, 5, 31, 13, 366, 22, 366, 366, 21, 11, 366, 366, 366, 366, 
15, 248, 35, 9, 65, 7, 366, 4, 22, 57, 320, 6, 5, 7, 32, 6, 3, 
10, 15, 4, 5, 366, 366, 14, 366, 15, 366, 366, 366, 5, 8, 366, 
12, 366, 10, 8, 366, 366, 366, 366, 366, 42, 366, 4, 366, 366, 
366, 21, 66, 366, 14, 15, 366, 366, 5, 366, 366, 366, 3, 366, 
366, 7, 366, 366, 366, 9, 7, 366, 52, 24, 366, 366, 64, 9, 10, 
366, 366, 366, 5, 366, 366, 5, 293, 21, 366, 366, 366, 6, 25, 
366, 6, 29, 16, 28, 366, 366, 366, 16, 15, 9, 10, 16, 11, 6, 
366, 366, 366, 366, 366, 22, 102, 42, 54, 32, 14, 8, 366)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-190L))
```

**I then apply the fine and gray function from  data:**

```
library(survival)
dat <- finegray(Surv(etime,event)~., data=df2)
```

**However, when inspecting the data frame dat for patient 34 for instance :**

```
>library(dplyr)
> dat %>%filter(ID==34)
  ID bridge follow_up_to_bridge one_year_status one_year_fu fgstart fgstop fgstatus      fgwt
1 34      2                  15               0         366       0     15        0 1.0000000
2 34      2                  15               0         366      19     21        0 0.9127950
3 34      2                  15               0         366      25     26        0 0.8143563
4 34      2                  15               0         366      32     35        0 0.7503058
>
```

**I don't understand two things about this patient who underwent transplantation on the 15th day:
1/ Why don't the "fgstop" and "fgstart" values follow each other (for example 15 to 19, 21 to 25, 26 to 32)?
2/ Why does the last "fgstop" value stop at 35 on line 4 when the patient is followed up until day 366?**

Of note this is the same for all other patients with a bridge to transplantation or long-term mechanical assistance for instance patient 96

```
>library(dplyr)
>dat %>%filter(ID==96)
  ID bridge follow_up_to_bridge one_year_status one_year_fu fgstart fgstop fgstatus      fgwt
1 96      2                  10               0         366       0     10        0 1.0000000
2 96      2                  10               0         366      11     12        0 0.9505500
3 96      2                  10               0         366      13     14        0 0.9359790
4 96      2                  10               0         366      14     15        0 0.8906897
5 96      2                  10               0         366      19     21        0 0.8130171
6 96      2                  10               0         366      25     26        0 0.7253388
7 96      2                  10               0         366      32     35        0 0.6682896
```

Thank you for your help